# Kivy Mobile App Development (Shape repeatedly drawing)

Tags: python, mobile, kivy, kivy-language

My problem is simple so I'll try and hurry. I am a newcomer to Kivy, I heard it was a simple and great way to start making apps, so I followed the tutorial series on Youtube with a guy by the name of "Tech with Tim". I'm currently on [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8vD-V5jpjBo&t=373s) video tutorial of his. At 5:55 in the tutorial you  can see him clicking over and over and the rectangle moves, great.

Here is all of MY code I wrote following the tutorial:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle
from kivy.graphics import Color


class Touch(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Touch, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        with self.canvas:
            Color(1, 0, 0, .5, mode='rgba')
            self.rect = Rectangle(pos=(0,0), size=(50, 50))

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        self.rect.pos = touch.pos
        print("Mouse down", touch)

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        self.rect.pos = touch.pos
        print("Mouse move", touch)


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Touch()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

You can see in the video link (from 6:11 to 6:13) that his code is the same. So how can I get the following result when I run mine? The result is [here](https://media.giphy.com/media/gIffFR0FmM3Z6S5Y1I/giphy.gif) What the heck could I possibly be doing wrong? My gut tells me maybe the drawing or screen refreshing is maybe because of the version I MIGHT be using, and he is using a different version? I'm completely stumped especially since I'm still learning kivy.

I'm thankful for any help I get that solves this issue. Please go easy on me if the answer was obvious and I overlooked it completely.

Comment: _maybe because of the version I MIGHT be using, and he is using a different version_ That was my first guess, too.

Comment: I'll look into that to be honest. Because there's no other explanation I can think of.

Comment: I copied your code, ran it and it worked exactly like in the video.

Comment: It is almost certainly not the Kivy version, nothing has changed around this behaviour. More likely it's your gpu drivers, make sure they are up to date.

Comment: If that's the case I'll look into updating my gpu drivers

Answer (score 0):

Update:

Just like inclement said as a reply to my first post, all I had to do was update my gpu. So I searched for "Device Manager" in my search bar, went to Display Adapters, and in my case I updated for my "Intel(R) HD Graphics 630" by right clicking and hitting update. Then restarting my computer. It works now. Thanks for everyone that replied.